# How to append browser name to the features on the left hand side of a cucumber extent report

Tags: selenium, cucumber, selenium-extent-report

I am working on a selenium project using cucumber. When I run my feature files, I use a testng xml file to run them on three different browsers, so each feature will appear three different times on the left hand side of the extent report. I was wondering if there is any way to append the name of the browser being used for each feature, much like how you can append the date and time for them.

Comment: You can probably use a Before hook to attach the browser name (as text) to each scenario, so long as you're using a config file or something of the like to do it with.

I haven't done it myself, so I am unsure, but that's what I would try first. - And as I have no code to show, I don't believe this to be as fully fledged as an answer needs to be

Comment: Yeah, that is what I am currently doing, but I was hoping to find a way to attach it to the features on the side instead of the scenarios.

Comment: Older versions of Cucumber did support BeforeFeature and AfterFeature hooks, but I believe they were removed (not sure why, they were useful for things like this). I’m going to raise a ticket on their github. Until they implement it, I doubt that this will be able to be done in that way, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I print the following details in the extent report.

```
    public static String getBrowser() {
            Capabilities cap = ((RemoteWebDriver) getDriver()).getCapabilities();
            String browserName = cap.getBrowserName().toLowerCase();
            return StringUtils.capitalize(browserName);
        }

    public static String getOs() {
        Capabilities cap = ((RemoteWebDriver) getDriver()).getCapabilities();
        String os = cap.getPlatform().toString();
        return os;
    }

    public static String getVersion() {
        Capabilities cap = ((RemoteWebDriver) getDriver()).getCapabilities();
        String v = cap.getVersion().toString();
        return v;
    }
```